# postgeSql many to many поиск

Tags: postgresql

есть таблицы chats, users и промежуточная chatsUsers

нужно найти чат в котором есть только два пользователя

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

даем userId 1,25 получаем только 2 чат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ch1.ChatID 
FROM chatsUsers ch1
JOIN chatsUsers ch2 on ch1.ChatID = ch2.ChatID
WHERE 
    ch1.UserID in (1, 25) and ch.UserID in (1, 25) and ch1.UserID <> ch2.UserID
```

Answer (score 1):

Альтернативный вариант с одним `JOIN`ом с использованием
массивов:

```sql
SELECT chat_id
  FROM chats
       LEFT JOIN chatsusers USING (chat_id)
 GROUP BY chat_id
HAVING COUNT(user_id) = 2
   AND ARRAY_AGG(user_id) @> ARRAY[1, 25]
   AND ARRAY_AGG(user_id) <@ ARRAY[1, 25]
;
```

*DB Fiddle*:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fSRSBg6Bdeer4LBd3bdMpQ/0.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
   ChatId
from chatsUsers
group by ChatId
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Не соблюдается условие поиска только по определённым `user_id`.

Comment: так написано `найти чат в котором есть только два пользователя`

Comment: @Ainar-G Да даже если расширить запрос - AND UserID IN (1,25)  суть не поменяется.

Comment: Поменяется.  Потому что теперь вам будут выдаваться чаты, где два _и более_ участника. Попробуйте сами.